# Backup program like Dropbox, but without online storage

Tags: backup, dropbox, home-server

I am interested in a program that does backups of my laptop periodically or continually. The destination is a computer at home that is always running. Is there a program which would facilitate this data transfer? This is very similar to the effect I get with dropbox, but since they store the data on their servers as well, the capacity is quite limited. I'd prefer to host my own space, but I don't want to have to write my own web-server like thing to do this; I'm sure someone's dealt with this before.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic, and I could have sworn I had answered a similar question this month. Maybe when I have a bit more time, I could write about it for the blog. Bitorrent sync is what you probably should be looking at. It lets you sync files over wan or lan, is pretty fast, and dosen't really use a central server for storage

Comment: Apologies if this is not an appropriate question for SU (this is my first question on the site). I get the impression that it is relevant, though, since there are a few similar questions now showing up in the "related" list, like http://superuser.com/questions/128590/alternative-to-dropbox-on-my-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use for [BitTorrent Sync](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

> Sync unlimited files between your own devices, or share a folder with friends and family to automatically sync anything.
>   File transfers are encrypted. Your information is never stored on a server in the cloud and your data is protected by private keys.
>   BitTorrent Sync is specifically designed to handle large files, so feel free to sync original, high quality, uncompressed files.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll out your own personal storage service with [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/).This article [here](http://lifehacker.com/5993596/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-cloud-storage-service-in-five-minutes-with-owncloud) will help you setup one.

OwnCloud is free and open source software that operates as a very simple way to set up your own syncing, Dropbox-like cloud storage system on your own server or web site.